# Access Query - All columns have LIKE

Tags: ms-access

Is there any way to search all columns in a table with a query ?
Something like this;

```
Select * FROM Table WHERE *(every column) LIKE '*sample*'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill, but it should give you a nudge in the right direction:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3774016/Searching-For-Text-Anywhere-In-a-Database.htm

You have two options:

```
Field1 + '§§' + Field2 + '§§' + Field3 .... LIKE 'sample'
```

('§§' is just an unike string so that you will not get a hit from overlapping fields)

or

```
Field1 LIKE 'sample' or Field2 LIKE 'sample' ...
```